# what does the su mean: process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out some code that I was given.  Can someone tell me what this means?

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
```

Especially the su.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used without any other kind of parameter, su changes the user ID to 0 (superuser) but does not change current path or environment.

Comment: What is often overlooked, but most critically important, is that su does not change the user ID of an existing process, rather it launches a new process (probably a shell) running as the requested user ID.

Comment: True! To change the execution ID of the current process, a program should attempt a call to setuid(uid) uid_t uid;

The su command by default starts a new shell, you can supply a command to be executed in the new shell.

Comment: Yes, but note that setuid() cannot let a previously unprivileged process become root, which is the capability that many who try to use 'su' programmatically (especially on android) are looking for, and will not find.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Unix command. It is used to switch active users. See for instance [this manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su) for details on what the command does. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_%28Unix%29) has some discussion about what the command name is believed to mean. I thought it was "switch user", but it wasn't that simple.

Comment: Ok, but why would someone want to switch active users in this case?

Comment: To do something their current user isn't allowed to.  Specifically, this code is likely starting shell process (implied) as root, and setting up a stream to send it commands, in order to have it do thing which the parent process lacks permission to do.  Note that this is **not supported** in official versions of android.

Comment: So if I want to create an Input stream else where in another thread, (so I don't kill the app when blocking for the input) should I replicate this pattern or is there a better way to do that?