# How su binary works?

Tags: android, superuser

I was browsing su binary code by Chainsdd when I was browsing it i saw it using `setuid(0)`
`setgid(0)`
to give root permissions

so my question is : **Can this method used in my own c library ?**

if not then how does the su does it? is it because it is placed in `/system` partition with some `chmod` or other operations like that have been perfomed on it?

Comment: this does not belong to android.stackexchange.com because im asking a programmatical question on my own c library

Comment: if you think it can help other please up-vote it :)

Comment: can anyone explain the  downvote??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su` executable file should have suid flag set. This allows it to start with uid and gid of its owner which should both be `root`.
From a normal application on Android it's impossible to call `setuid(0)` or `setgid(0)` because they're all started with arbitrary non-root uid and gid.

Comment: @llya  why is my question downvoted?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not the one who downvoted it.

Comment: Maybe because it's a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028032/how-does-su-work-on-android-and-what-are-the-pre-requisites-for-it-to-work-wha

Comment: but my question is diffreent and it is according to your answer