# Android java process returns 1 when executing "su"

Tags: java, android, mkdir, exit-code

i'm trying to write onto the "/data/myFolder" folder on the android virtual device during test and to do that, i do:

```
String[] cmd ={"su", "mkdir", dir};
    int out = 99;

    try {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        out = p.waitFor();
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(p.getErrorStream());
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
        while (in.read(bytes) != -1) {

        }

        in.close();
        logger.info("exit status:" + out);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.severe("IOException " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.severe("InterruptedException " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (out != 0) {
        logger.severe("Folder " + dir + " not created,exit status: " + out);
    }
```

or i've tried

```
String cmd ={"su mkdir" + dir};
```

but the exit status is 1 and it not create any folder. using su mkdir /data/myFolder from adb shell works fine. 
Why this code? what means? (i know it means that something went wrong, but what? didn't find any documentation about android mkdir exit code values).
Thank's

Comment: What happens if you add a space to the thing you tried: `String cmd = "su mkdir " + dir;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does the su mean: process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100662/what-does-the-su-mean-process-runtime-getruntime-execsu)

Comment: i get the same error code (1)

Comment: Of course you get. You are still executing "su", not "mkdir". Please do a Google search about what the "su"-command actually does.

Comment: @Torben you are right, i was executing su command and not mkdir as root. 
now String cmd = "mkdir "+ dir; Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); works fine.

Answer (score 2):

error code 1 is [EPERM /* Not super-user */](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/lk/+/dima/for-travis/include/errno.h) on Android if anyone is curious.

So there's something not working right with your root

Answer (score 0):

I use below code to give commands

```
try {
            Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);
            OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
            byte[] mScreenBuffer = ("mkdir dir ")
                    .getBytes();
            os.write(mScreenBuffer);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            sh.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: like this, i redirect the sdtOutput and than i write into it "mkdir dir ". doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: Please specify what part exactly confuses you.

Comment: is not it confuses me, the problem is that like you wrote, i write "mkdir dir " to the standard output, i don't execute "mkdir dir " command.

Comment: If u look at the code it's BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(p.getErrorStream()); and it's input and error streams

Comment: i'm talking about your answer, and you wrote OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();

Comment: That is how it should be. you need to write on the outPut Stream of the Process then only it will execute